# How to create `.d.ts` with webpack?

Tags: typescript, webpack

### question

How can I generate a d.ts file that can be adapted to minified JS files generated by webpack?

### situation

There are 2 projects.

- `lib project`
  Wrote in TypeScript. Build by webpack. Package like node.
- `other my project`
  Wrote in TypeScript. Build by webpack. use `lib project`.

#### lib project(TypeScript project)

Library project. Build by webpack.
webpack create bundled JS.
bundled JS's function name is not same as TS file.
*.d.ts file is created powered by ts-loader(ts compiler).
So, *.d.ts's function name is same as TS file.

#### other my project(TypeScript project, use lib project)

import lib project.(npm)
`npm install --save "lib-project"`
And use `lib project`'s *.d.ts.
Build is OK, but runtime error occur because lib project's function name is not same as *.d.ts file's.
ex: `lib.func() is not defined.`